# All addons missing after upgrading Blender from 2.83-4 to 2.90

Tags: add-on, installation, linux

I'm on Arch Linux and after running "sudo pacman -Su" to upgrade blender, my addons disappeared. I've tried manually installing the addons from "/usr/share/blender/2.90/scripts/addons" but that throws an error. I've also tried reinstalling blender and its dependencies but I still run into the same issue. The only solution that works for me is to download the binaries from blender.org but that would still leave me with a "broken" package. Has anyone else run into this issue before? And if so, is it related to Arch's blender package or could it be something else?

I'd appreciate any insight into the issue.

[image: Missing Addons]

[image]

Comment: Probably a bug, remember that 2.90 is not 100% stable and is going to last a few months. You could make a report over Blender Bug report website here: https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/

Comment: install the file from blender.org directly, not from repositories, snap or flatpack.

Comment: Most likely a broken Arch package, see ticket [T80347](https://developer.blender.org/T80347).