# Missing addons in blender 3.5 (Fedora 37)

Tags: add-on, linux

I recently upgraded to Fedora 37 (from 35). I just noticed blender is missing the ability to import FBX files. Moreover, my Add-ons is basically empty (nothing shows up when searching for fbx):

[image]

After launching from the terminal I am guessing this is why:

```
BLT_lang_init: 'locale' data path for translations not found, continuing
Read prefs: /home/pknowles/.config/blender/3.5/config/userpref.blend
Failed to open dir (No such file or directory): /run/user/1000/gvfs/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_anim_bvh'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_curve_svg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_mesh_ply'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_mesh_stl'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_mesh_uv_layout'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_scene_fbx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_scene_gltf2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_scene_obj'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_scene_x3d'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pose_library'
```

Specifically, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_scene_fbx'`.

It seems I only have the `cycles` renderer in `/usr/share/blender/3.5/scripts/addons/` and no other addons. Are these intended to be there? How can I get the FBX import feature back?

I tried `sudo dnf reinstall blender` and this succeeded without error, but I still have the same issue. I'm wondering if addons are now provided in a different package, but `sudo dnf list \*blender\*` isn't showing anything new.

[edit] nearly the same as [All addons missing after upgrading Blender from 2.83-4 to 2.90](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193011/all-addons-missing-after-upgrading-blender-from-2-83-4-to-2-90)

Comment: For now I'm just running the pre-built from https://www.blender.org/download/ as suggested in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203039/add-ons-in-a-linux-installation-of-blender